# How write this join criteria in sql?

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements, teradata, criteria

I have column_x that holds either 20 digits or 22 digits numbers, and column_Y that holds 22 digits.

If when column_x's number is 20 digits long, I want to join on column_Y with only numbers in column_Y that has the second digit NOT equal to 0.
Else (when column_x number is 22 digits long), I want to join column_x with column_Y's numbers normally.

How to do this?

For example,

if column X has the numbers 00000000000579701673 (20 digits) and 0000000000000957821317 (22 digits), and column Y has the numbers 9900000000000579701673 (22 digits) and 0000000000000957821317 (22 digits), I want to join 00000000000579701673 (20 digits) from column_x with 9900000000000579701673 (22 digits) from column_Y and 0000000000000957821317 (22 digits) from column_x with 0000000000000957821317 (22 digits) from column_Y

if column_X is 20 digits the prefix is anywhere from '01' to '99'
I am using teradata sql assist

Comment: So if X is 20 digits need to tack on a 99 prefix?

Comment: @June7 if 20 digits the prefix is anywhere from '01' to '99' thanks!

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please show what you are able to do. [ask] [help] [mre]

Comment: @philipxy done thanks!

Comment: Please act on all of my comment & its links.

Comment: If column X has 22 digits, are the first two digits always the same `00`? Then the join will be simply `on right(column_x, 20)= right(column_y, 20)`, effectively ignoring the first two chars.

Comment: @dnoeth but I don't want to join a 20 digit from column X with the wrong row in column Y because if X has 20 digits then it must be joined with column Y that begins with '01' or to '99'

Comment: Will the last 9 digits be unique values in each column? Can't just join on the last 9 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your logic you simple need to prepend `'99'` if the string is only 20 chars (similar to June7's answer but using Standard SQL/Teradata syntax):

```
join ...
on case when char_length(column_x) = 20 then '99' else '' end || column_x = column_y
```

Edit:

Based on your comment *if X has 20 digits then it must be joined with column Y that begins with '01' or to '99'* this might be what you want:

```
on right(column_x, 20)= right(column_y, 20)
and (char_length(column_x) = 22 
     or substr(column_y, 1, 2) <> '00')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not always "99"

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you're looking for, and I've added comments on the two join conditions that explain my understanding. Let me know if I've misunderstood anything. I've never used teradata SQL so you might need to change my uses of LEN to LENGTH.

```
select * 
from x
inner join y
-- if X is 22 characters long, join with y normally
ON (LEN(x.id) = 22 AND x.id = y.id)
-- if x is 20 characters long, join with y if the first two digits are not 00
   OR (LEN(x.id) = 20 AND LEFT(y.id, 2) <> '00')
```